# Форматировать текст на canvas

Tags: canvas, html, html5

У canvas (HTML5) для форматирования текста есть только два свойства: `font` и `fontSize` для определения шрифта и размера.

Возможно ли как-то сделать текст, например, жирным? Или курсивным?

// я могу, конечно, написать font = 'Arial bold', но это ведь не с каждым шрифтом прокатит!

Comment: UPD. Сорри, fontSize нету: пишется font = 'size font'

Comment: UPD2. Нашёл способ :)
Пишется font = 'bold italic 20px Arial'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, разумеется, жирным и курсивным можно.

Для этого в ctx.font формируется строка:

```
"[bold ][italic ][<Number>px ]<FontFamily>"
```

т.о. для жирного Arial в 10 пикселей строка будет иметь вид:

```
"bold 10px Arial"
```

UPD: Для получения подчеркнутого/зачеркнутого шрифта придется вычислять координаты и рисовать линию через stroke